# How to load file from classpath with Spring 3?

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I have defined an ClassPathResource bean like so:

```
<bean id="ivsInputResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <qualifier value="ivs" />
    <constructor-arg index="0"
        value="classpath*:IVS90test.csv"/>
</bean>
```

But when the resource bean is injected, my app breaks with this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): class path resource [classpath*:IVS90test.csv]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:256)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
```

Obviously the resource cannot be found. When using FileSystemResource (with adjusted path) my app does work.

How to properly load files from the classpath?

My project is layed out as shown:

[image: screenshot of project layout in eclipse]

Comment: If you use the ClassPathResource class, do you need to prefix it with  'classpath*:'?

Comment: nope indeed, solved it, if you put this comment as an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify `classpath:` in the path to your file when using [ClassPathResource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html)

> **Parameters**:
>   path - the absolute path within the classpath

Here, *absolute path* means from the root of the resources folder, so all you need to do is change it to

```
<bean id="ivsInputResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <qualifier value="ivs" />
    <constructor-arg index="0"
        value="IVS90test.csv"/>
</bean>
```